# In SQL, how can I pick any two combinations from a list of three variables

Tags: sql, sas

Suppose I have 3 possible CHAR variables A,B,C

I need to find all combinations of two from the list of these three.

The possibilities would be A,B or A,C or C,B and C,A.

Comment: Which database are you using (mysql, oracle, etc)? Please add the appropriate tag to your question.

Comment: You want both `A, C` and `C, A`. Why not `B, A` or `B, C` too?

Comment: Hi, first you work out a bit on a query then you ask about that query. This looks like you want an answer without an effort?!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Given a your values are in a table, eg:

```
create table chars (
  ch char
);
insert into chars values ('A');
insert into chars values ('B');
insert into chars values ('C');
```

For all [*combinations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), you can use:

```
select *
from chars c1
join chars c2 on c1.ch < c2.ch
```

For all [*permutations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), you can use:

```
select *
from chars c1
join chars c2 on c1.ch != c2.ch
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/161e2a/2).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, however, all two item combinations of three variables requires three unions.

```
proc sql;
  create table have
  ( c1 char(1)
  , c2 char(1)
  , c3 char(1)
  );


  insert into have 
    values ('A','P','X')
    values ('B','Q','Y')
  ;

  create table want as
  select 
    'c1' as item1, p12_1.c1 as item1value
  , 'c2' as item2, p12_2.c2 as item2value 
  from have as p12_1 cross join have as p12_2
  union 
  select
    'c1' as item1, p13_1.c1 as item1value
  , 'c3' as item2, p13_2.c3 as item2value
  from have as p13_1 cross join have as p13_2
  union 
  select 
    'c2' as item1, p23_1.c2 as item1value
  , 'c3' as item2, p23_2.c3 as item2value
  from have as p23_1 cross join have as p23_2
  ;
```